# Nested hash not passed in from attributes to Chef recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra

I'm currently writing a rails_web cookbook that already offers a definition for a rails_web_app. In the default recipe of the cookbook, I want to iterate through each app (a hash of symbols keyed to objects like so):

```
default["rails_web"]["apps"] = [ { name: "my_app",
                             server_name: "localhost",
                             database_info: {
                                :host => "127.0.0.1",
                                :port => 5432,
                                :username => "postgres",
                                :password => "whocaresatm"
                               }
                           } ]
```

And pass app["database_info"] to the opscode's database cookbook's postgresql_database LWRP.

I thought this would be possible by doing:

```
apps.each do |app|
  rails_web_app app["name"] do
    server_name app["server_name"]
  end
  postgresql_database app["name"] do
    connection app["database_info"]
    action :create
  end
end
```

Because my rails_web_app definition already works by extracting information from the above hash, and the database cookbook authors showcase:

```
postgresql_connection_info = {
  :host     => '127.0.0.1',
  :port     => node['postgresql']['config']['port'],
  :username => 'postgres',
  :password => node['postgresql']['password']['postgres']
}

postgresql_database 'foo' do
  connection postgresql_connection_info
  action     :create
end
```

But, when I try to run the default recipe (cookbook compilation works fine,) I get

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
10.5.32.101   ----------------------------------
10.5.32.101   Required argument connection is missing!
10.5.32.101   
10.5.32.101   Cookbook Trace:
10.5.32.101   ---------------
10.5.32.101     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/database/libraries/resource_database.rb:41:in `connection'
10.5.32.101     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rails_web/recipes/default.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
10.5.32.101     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rails_web/recipes/default.rb:41:in `block in from_file'
10.5.32.101     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rails_web/recipes/default.rb:37:in `each'
10.5.32.101     /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rails_web/recipes/default.rb:37:in `from_file'
10.5.32.101   
10.5.32.101   Relevant File Content:
10.5.32.101   ----------------------
10.5.32.101   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/database/libraries/resource_database.rb:
10.5.32.101   
10.5.32.101    34:            :database_name,
10.5.32.101    35:            arg,
10.5.32.101    36:            kind_of: String
10.5.32.101    37:          )
10.5.32.101    38:        end
10.5.32.101    39:  
10.5.32.101    40:        def connection(arg = nil)
10.5.32.101    41>>         set_or_return(
10.5.32.101    42:            :connection,
10.5.32.101    43:            arg,
10.5.32.101    44:            required: true
10.5.32.101    45:          )
10.5.32.101    46:        end
10.5.32.101    47:  
10.5.32.101    48:        def sql(arg = nil, &block)
10.5.32.101    49:          arg ||= block
10.5.32.101    50:          set_or_return(
```

What am I missing here? Obviously nil is being passed in but I don't quite understand how the rails_web_app definition works perfectly taking in a string from the apps[] attribute while the postgresql_database LWRP can't handle a hash of symbols as keys mapped to other stuff. Something's off on my syntax but tweaking for some time hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Comment: I assume your problem could come from mixing the syntax of hashes, try `host: "127.0.0.1",` instead of old syntax `:host => "127.0.0.1"` (The hash in chef attributes being a modified version of ruby hash, some unexpected result is to happen when mixing types. (last idea coming to my mind, use `app[:database_connection]`  in the attribute)

Comment: Setting all hashes to new syntax brought back the same error. Wrote a quick and dirty postgresql stand-in cookbook as a replacement. Thank you for answering back!